# Respuesta incompleta recibida de la aplicación Node JS

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

estoy implementanto mi aplicacion en cpanel con node js y express pero me sale el error he buscado soluciones pero no me funcionan.

`Incomplete response received from application`

como puedo solucionar este error, que deberia agregarle o cambiar para que funcione mi aplicacion.

**App.js**

```
const { json } = require('express');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const session = require('express-session');

app.use(express(json))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));

app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

const OperadorRouter = require('./routes/OperadorRoutes')
const SupervisorRouter = require('./routes/SupervisorRoutes')
const MecanicoRouter = require('./routes/MecanicoRoutes')
const AdministradorRouter = require('./routes/AdministradorRoutes')
const UsuarioRouter = require('./routes/UsuarioRouter')

app.get('/',(req, res)=>{
    res.render('index')
})


app.use('/Operador/',OperadorRouter)
app.use('/Supervisor/',SupervisorRouter)
app.use('/Mecanico/',MecanicoRouter)
app.use('/Administrador/',AdministradorRouter)
app.use('/Login/',UsuarioRouter)

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(5000, ()=>{
    console.log("SERVER corriendo en http://localhost:5000")
})
```

Comment: Cuándo te arroja ese error? Al ejecutar la app o al utilizar algun endpoint en específico?

Comment: con todos los endpoints que tengo

Comment: Podrías agregar el código de por lo menos 1 handler que te de ese error? Te recomiendo que leas [example]